# Configuration *.tra file for TIBCO Business Studio

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works, businessworks, tibco-designer

Can anyone tell me where I can find the TIBCO Business Studio *.tra configuration file?
I made small research and it turned out that this would be `TIBCOBusinessStudio.ini`
However, once I'll add my custom property, like `user.timezone=UTC` and I'll check in TIBCO Business Studio config (in Help-> Instalation info -> tab Configuration), I can see that my value is set there, but afterwards default value is set, like:

```
[...]
user.timezone=Europe/Belgrade
[...]
user.timezone=UTC
[...]
```

It sees that simply my value is overwritten from somewhere else.

What I can find the source of that setup?